# finish my current background activity when call ringing android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, android-broadcast

I have application that use audio device of the phone, I want my activity to be finish when any call come to my device

This is the code

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {

            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                // Send local broadcast to set pin code in the dialog
                Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                broadcast.setAction(ThurayaConstants.INCOMING_CALL);
                mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added this class to listen to global receiver in the manifest file to detect when any call come to my device.

and in my fragment I register the following receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver   mIncomingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            getActivity().finish();
        }
    };
```

The problem that my activity is not closed , can any one help here ???

Comment: Why would you want the activity to go away for only a call? Would you want it to be cancelled if an alarm screen popped up? Maybe you should consider an activity with no history. See the [`activity:noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) attribute.

Comment: have you tried  `context.finish()` ?